# Shiny - rehashing changed passwords stored in SQL

Tags: sql, mysql, r, shiny, shinyauthr

Fairly new user to Shiny, I'm currently working on an application that stores registered user details in SQL and hashes their passwords using the shinyauthr package during registration.
I've been working on allowing users to edit their details via the app which updates the SQL table, and I'm wondering if it's possible for users to edit their (non-hashed) password and have their new password hashed again to update the SQL details, and if so, how might this be done?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm inferring that your "real" database has its own credentials to connect, so what you're doing when you authenticate a user is verify that the hash of their provided password matches the hash in your real database (btw, I hope you're [salting the hashes](https://auth0.com/blog/adding-salt-to-hashing-a-better-way-to-store-passwords/) with randomly-generated salts). It seems reasonable to have the user provide "old pass, new pass, new pass again" to update your table. Is this not working in practice?

Comment: To be sure, though, by *"edit their (non-hashed) password"*, I'm assuming you mean "replace" their old password with a new password; a user should never "see" the contents of their previous password. In fact, if you're storing the hash, you won't know it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I just went through quite a bit of testing to find out that ... `loginServer` accepts (only) a static `data=` argument. This means that when _one_ person changes their password, in order to accept that new password, you'll need to restart all shiny instances. This seems to be a fundamental oversight in `shinyauthr`, I suggest you [reach out to the author](https://github.com/PaulC91/shinyauthr/issues/new/choose) and request one of: (1) add the ability to change the data in realtime; (2) use a callback function instead of data; (3) use a database. All three seem reasonable to me.

Comment: Okay, it's already been discussed a few times: https://github.com/PaulC91/shinyauthr/issues/24#issuecomment-1091428904 being the author's basic answer: update the data and force a reload of the shiny session.

Comment: @r2evans huge help, thanks for that, all sorted now. Thanks everyone, appreciate it!